# Grails mongodb gorm criteria query

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I am using *grails(2.3.7)* *mongodb gorm* plugin *mongodb:3.0.1.*
I have following collection in db

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567eac392c56fd49950e2441"),
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "commentText" : "test comments!",
                        "userId" : "patient@gmail.com",
                        "likes" : 10,
                        "date" : "2015-12-25T10:34:53.048Z"
                },
                {
                        "commentText" : "master piece",
                        "userId" : "patient@gmail.com",
                        "likes" : 12,
                        "date" : "2015-12-25T10:34:53.052Z"
                },
                {
                        "commentText" : "test comments!",
                        "userId" : "patient@gmail.com",
                        "likes" : 10,
                        "date" : "2015-12-25T10:34:53.048Z"
                },
                {
                        "commentText" : "master piece",
                        "userId" : "patient@gmail.com",
                        "likes" : 12,
                        "date" : "2015-12-25T10:34:53.052Z"
                }
        ],
        "doctorUserId" : "doctor2@gmail.com",
        "recommendation" : 0,
        "version" : NumberLong(2)
}
```

Now I want to query inside comments parameter order by date (inside comment) using mongoDB gorm

Thanks inadvance

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Post the code you tried and explain the problem facing . Posting your requirement does not suffice

Comment: def commentCriteria=DoctorSocial.createCriteria()
def results=commentCriteria.list(max:10) {
 eq("doctorUserId",params.doctorId)
}

Comment: def commentCriteria=DoctorSocial.createCriteria()
def results=commentCriteria.list(max:10) {
 eq("doctorUserId",params.doctorId)
}

query will fetch the collection which matches doctorId. and in mongoDB comments is stored as array and i dont know how to query inside array using mongoDB gorm 
Query i am trying inside mongoDB is 
db.doctorSocial.find({doctorUserId:"doctor2@gmail.com"},{comments: {$elemMatch:{userId:"patient@gmail.com"}}}).pretty()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for correct sorting by date all your date fields need to have [Date type](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/bson-types/) not string. So your date field should look like this:

```
date: ISODate("2015-12-26T16:33:44.592Z")
```

You can sort nested array using mongodb [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/aggregation/). Try the following code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$comments"}, 
    {$sort: {'comments.date': 1} }, 
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id', 
        comments: {$push: '$comments'}, 
        version: {$first: "$version"}, 
        doctorUserId: {$first: "$doctorUserId"},
        recommendation: {$first: "$recommendation"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: i need to query the data using MongoDB GORM plugin in grails https://grails.org/plugin/mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Converting Volodymyr Synytskyi's answer to Grails/GORM:

```
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject(['$unwind': '$comments']);

DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject(['$sort': [
    'comments.date' : 1
]]);

DBObject group = new BasicDBObject(['$group': [
    '_id'           : '$_id', 
    'comments'      : ['$push' : '$comments'], 
    'version'       : ['$first': '$version'], 
    'doctorUserId'  : ['$first': '$doctorUserId'],
    'recommendation': ['$first': '$recommendation']
]]);

DBColleciton collection = DoctorSocial.collection;
AggregationOutput aggregationOutput = collection.aggregate([unwind, sort, group]);
aggregationOutput.results().each { dbObject ->
    // Do something with your results
}
```

Note: The above is untested so some tweaking might be in order, but similar use of aggregates works just fine in my app.